# One repo depends on files in another repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab, hugo

I have two large repos:

`Repo 1` contains, among other things, files for my [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) site. The site files are held in subdirectory of `Repo 1`.

`Repo 2` contains several data assets which I would like to leverage in my site build. `Repo 2` also contains some subdirectories which aren't important for the Hugo site.

What is the best way to keep these two repos in sync? In other words, how do I ensure that `Repo 1` always has access to the most up to date versions of important files from `Repo 2`, while at the same time not flooding `Repo 1` with unnecessary files from `Repo 2`?

Comment: Where are the repos hosted?
Do you need files from the Repo 2 in Repo 1, when you run a build pipeline?
If yes, what CI/CD you use?

Answer (score 0):

Init both repos as Go mods:
i.e. create a go.mod file at root of both, a la:
`module github.com/your-organization/your-repo` <- Each with it's own of course.

Then in the config (config.toml/.yaml whatever) on the repo where you want to pull files/assets to:

```
[[module.imports]]  
    path = "github.com/your-org/your-repo-you-want-to-get"  
    disable=false  
    ignoreConfig=true  <- IF that repo has it's own config
    [[module.imports.mounts]]  
    source = "assets/images" <- Wherever you want to get
    target = "assets/images" <- Wherever you want to place
```

Then learn the hugo mod commands (clean, tidy, get) to update, clean out cache, etc.

Let me know.